# use phpmailer to send email from localhost to gmail: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

i want to send an email from localhost to gmail, but it says "SMTP connect() failed"
here is my code. I've also tried to change configuration php.ini and sendmail.ini but no luck.
Thank you.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();       
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'asd@gmail.com';               
    $mail->Password = 'password';                   

    $mail->From = 'from@example.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
    $mail->addAddress('asd@gmail.com');           

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                            
    $mail->isHTML(true);                          

    $mail->Subject = 'Email'
    $mail->Body    = "This is body";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8629554/1864610)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, those other answers won't help you. You should be using `Port = 587` amd `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`, but that's not the problem - you have a DNS or network issue preventing you from connecting, and the same thing would prevent any other SMTP solution from working.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following :

- Ensure that the PHPMailer library is included in the code.
- Ensure that you are internet connection from localhost is not inhibited by any proxy.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

check the line $mail->Subject = 'Email' for a missing ;